# Getting the coordinates of every observation at each iteration of kmeans in R

Tags: r, k-means

I would like to construct an animation of the kmeans clustering algorithm in R.  The animation would show each of the observations (rows) in the the dataset plotted in 2 (or 3) dimensions and then have them move into their clusters as each iteration ticks by.

For this I would need to access the coordinates of the observations at each iteration. Where in the kmeans package can I access these?

Thanks,

Comment: In the k-means algorithm, the coordinates of the observations do not change. Instead, the centroids (means) of the clusters move from one iteration to the next. The k-means algorithm is extremely simple, you should be able to code a basic version from scratch in a couple minutes for your animation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `kmeans()` outputs this kind of tracing information. Your best best may be to re-run `kmeans()` multiple times, carrying over cluster centers.

```
set.seed(1)
clus.1 <- kmeans(iris[,1:2],5,iter.max=1)
clus.2 <- kmeans(iris[,1:2],centers=clus.1$centers,iter.max=1)
clus.3 <- kmeans(iris[,1:2],centers=clus.2$centers,iter.max=1)

changing <- which(apply(cbind(clus.1$cluster,clus.2$cluster,clus.3$cluster),1,sd)>0)
changing
opar <- par(mfrow=c(1,3))
    plot(iris[,c(1,2)],col=clus.1$cluster,pch=19,main="Iteration 1")
    points(iris[changing,c(1,2)],pch=21,cex=2)
    plot(iris[,c(1,2)],col=clus.2$cluster,pch=19,main="Iteration 2")
    points(iris[changing,c(1,2)],pch=21,cex=2)
    plot(iris[,c(1,2)],col=clus.3$cluster,pch=19,main="Iteration 3")
    points(iris[changing,c(1,2)],pch=21,cex=2)
par(opar)
```

[image]

I indicate the points that do change cluster membership; unfortunately, only one does do so, because `kmeans()` just converges so darn fast ;-)

You write that you would like to "have them move into their clusters as each iteration ticks by". Of course points don't *move* in clustering algorithms. So a color-coded representation like this one is your best bet.

In more than two dimensions, you can try `pairs()`, or just concentrate on two dimensions. Be prepared to explain why n-dimensional clusters don't look "cluster-like" when projected to two dimensions.

Comment: Excellent, good answer thank you. And yes, sorry I meant the centroids animating. There doesn't seem to be an option to mark this as correct.  Another link I found is this one: http://mcube.nju.edu.cn/jokergoo/animation-of-kmeans-clustering.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If you want to "accept" my answer, just click on the checkmark underneath the vote count for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the process of getting convergence by using `tryCatch` as follows

```
set.seed(1337)
df = iris[,1:2]


dfCluster<-kmeans(df,centers=3, iter.max = 1)
  plot(df[,1], df[,2], col=dfCluster$cluster,pch=19,cex=2, main="iter 1")
  points(dfCluster$centers,col=1:5,pch=3,cex=3,lwd=3)

cent <- list(dfCluster$centers)

max_iter = 10

for (i in 2:max_iter){
  tryCatch({
    dfCluster <- kmeans(df,centers = dfCluster$centers, iter.max = 1)
    done <- TRUE
  }, 
  warning=function(w) {done <- FALSE})
  cent[[i]] <- dfCluster$centers
  if(done) break
}
```

`cent` is a list with the centers of the cluster at each iteration

```
cent
[[1]]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1     6.795833    3.081250
2     5.769231    2.678846
3     5.006000    3.428000

[[2]]
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1     6.812766    3.074468
2     5.773585    2.692453
3     5.006000    3.428000
```

To plot this see [How to visualize k-means centroids for each iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060527/how-to-visualize-k-means-centroids-for-each-iteration/27062052#27062052)