# How to visualize k-means centroids for each iteration?

Tags: r, k-means

I would like to graphically demostrate the behavior of k-means by plotting iterations of the algorithm from a starting value (at (3,5),(6,2),(8,3)) of initial cluster till the cluster centers.
Each iteration may correspond to a single plot with centroids and clusters.

Given:

```
                x<-c(3,6,8,1,2,2,6,6,7,7,8,8)
                y<-c(5,2,3,5,4,6,1,8,3,6,1,7)


                df<-data.frame(x,y)
                dfCluster<-kmeans(df,centers=3) # with 3 centroids
```

I would like to use the first three tuples as my initial cluster and track the movement of the centroids.

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916337/getting-the-coordinates-of-every-observation-at-each-iteration-of-kmeans-in-r?

Comment: THX for that advice. However, I stuggle to define the starting values as explained in the initial example. Given the data above I clus.1 <- kmeans(df[1:3,],3,iter.max=1) but that gives error Error: number of cluster centres must lie between 1 and nrow(x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `tryCatch` to automate the the process of stopping when conversion is reached:
I use the iris-data set because there kmeans needs 2 iterations (the (6,3.5)-Point switches)

```
set.seed(1337)
df = iris[,1:2]


dfCluster<-kmeans(df,centers=3, iter.max = 1)
  plot(df[,1], df[,2], col=dfCluster$cluster,pch=19,cex=2, main="iter 1")
  points(dfCluster$centers,col=1:5,pch=3,cex=3,lwd=3)

max_iter = 10

for (i in 2:max_iter){
  tryCatch({
    dfCluster <- kmeans(df,centers = dfCluster$centers, iter.max = 1)
    done <- TRUE
  }, 
  warning=function(w) {done <- FALSE})
  plot(df[,1], df[,2], col=dfCluster$cluster,pch=19,cex=2, main=paste("iter",i))
  points(dfCluster$centers,col=1:5,pch=3,cex=3,lwd=3)
  if(done) break
}
```

Result:
[image]
[image]

If you want to get the coordinates at each iteration-step see here: [Getting the coordinates of every observation at each iteration of kmeans in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916337/getting-the-coordinates-of-every-observation-at-each-iteration-of-kmeans-in-r/27062160#27062160)

Comment: thats very nice thank you a lot for the function. how can i inlcude the starting centroids at (3,5),(6,2),(8,3)? Copy and paste of your code using iris produces only the second iter graphically

Comment: Just save a starting matrix `start <- matrix(c(3,5,6,2,8,3), 3, byrow = TRUE)` and in the 3rd line do `..., centers = start, ...` instead of `..., centers = 3, ...`

Comment: yes thats its. thanks. however the initial graphical iteration iter1 is omitted. only the last one is shown, that is iter 2. copying your example from above with iris, I had just iter 2 as well.

Comment: use RStudio to click trough the plots, or `par(mfrow=c(2,1))` to plot them in one image or save the plots using `png` see `?png` how this works

Comment: The question was more about the iterations rather than the plot. if i would have data which requires more iteration to find the centroids how can I extand your code. because putting randomly data sets into your code gives two iterations back...thx again